# Determine if $f(x,y)=e^{-xy}\cos(2x)\cos(y)$ is integrable via Fubini

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I was told to determine whether $f(x,y)=e^{-xy}\cos(2x)\cos(y)$ is integrable over $(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$ via the contrapositive of Fubini's theorem, according to wolfram alpha (screenshot below), the two repeated calculations are equal. I don't think that gives me anything. Any hint on how to proceed is appreciated. Thank you!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please include the result you obtained for the "two repeated calculations" [with your step]. This way someone here can check what you have done.